# Is ES6 class extend fully equivalent to Object.assign based extending of an object?

Tags: ecmascript-6

In other words are these two different blocks of code fully equivalent?

## ES6 class extend based

```
class Child extends Parent {
    // Define my subclass
}
var myInstance = new Child();
```

## Object.assign based

```
var myInstance = Object.assign(new Parent(), {
   // Define my subclass
}
```

In my particular use case I am trying to extend (Facebook's) Flux Dispatcher. In their examples they use Object.assign. I would like to ES6 class extend, but I am worried that there are subtle differences between the two so I should stick with Object.assign.

Comment: There are differences but the question is whether the affect you. E.g. in the first case you have `myInstance instanceOf Child === true`, which obviously is not the case in the second example.

Comment: I guess that you mean this dispatcher example: https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/docs/TodoList.md

Comment: Yes that is the example code I was looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these code blocks are not equivalent

In the class inheritance example you will get a new constructor which makes objects having features from parent class.

Extending objects via `Object.assign` is a example of [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).
You just add some properties to one instance but not change all future children.

Unlike child classes, an instance after extension will still have the `constructor` property pointing to the `Parent`. It means that you can't recognize extended child among non-extended, because they all have the same constructor and operator `instanceof` will give the same result. Also you can't get access to overridden methods in child, because you will lose the link to it.

As for flux's dispatcher [in this example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/docs/TodoList.md), you can't extend it via class inheritance, because there is no constructor which you can provide as a parent.