# What are the differences between using Object.assign and class/extends?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flux

I am trying to understand how Facebook Flux works by looking at the source code of their [flux chat example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-chat).

There, I saw [this code](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/MessageStore.js#L44-L94):

```
var MessageStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

  emitChange: function() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  },

  /**
   * @param {function} callback
   */
  addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },
  ...
}

...

module.exports = MessageStore;
```

...where assign is just polyfilled Object.assign from ES6 spec.

Hm. Would this code, using classes and extends instead, work? Would it mean the same thing? What are differences and advantages/disadvantages of this approach?

```
class MessageStore extends EventEmitter {
    emitChange() {
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    }

    addChangeListener(callback) {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    }

    ...
}

module.exports = new MessageStore();
```

I am asking, because, coming from other languages, I intuitively understand class/extends, while prototype-based inheritance is always a little unclear to me.

Comment: `Object.assign` only copies properties, there is no inheritance.

Comment: But the code, as I wrote it, should be equivalent, no? Maybe except for the one class that is created and used only once.

Comment: Similar, but *not* identical, question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548562/is-es6-class-extend-fully-equivalent-to-object-assign-based-extending-of-an-obje

Comment: That depends on whether `EventEmitter.prototype` will be modified. If you want inheritance, also consider using `Object.assign(Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype), {...})`

Comment: Hm. Both codes would do the same if the `EventEmitter.prototype` was modified, no?

Comment: Another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965844/lodash-difference-between-extend-assign-and-merge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is working code that you can use with regards to ES6 syntax and your situation:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';
const CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

class MessageStore extends EventEmitter {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  addChangeListener = (callback) => {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  removeChangeListener = (callback) => {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  emitChange = () => {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  }

}
```

Note, I prefer the ES6 function literal syntax because it ensures that "this" is always bound to the enclosing object context.

For a fully working ES6 store example, please feel free to review the [stores code in my Babel React Starter App](https://github.com/arcseldon/react-babel-webpack-starter-app/blob/master/src/stores/authorStore.js)

This is also a useful reference on [ES6 classes](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html) that visually explains what is going on inside the body of a class definition.

Comment: I don't get the function literal syntax. How would it be different without it? `this` will refer to the object even when it is a normal function, as in my question, no?

Comment: @KarelBílek - you are right here. However, more generally, have been bitten other times eg with "helper functions" extending from React.Component. - a common pattern you see is the need to explicitly bind to the function you use eg  "onPress={this.onLoginPressed.bind(this)}"  However, if you declare your onLoginPressed function using above syntax eg. onLoginPressed = () => {
    console.log('Attempting to log in with username ' + this.state.username);
}  then you no longer need to bind explicity. eg. simply use "onPress={this.onLoginPressed}"  as a result, prefer this syntax so no doubts.

Answer (score 0):

**class extends:***
You are extending a generic class, which is sometimes exactly what you want, e.g. a `button` extends a `domElement`, but a `button` should not extend an `EventEmitter` because they have nothing in common.

**Object.assign:**
With Object.assign you are "mixin" a new functionality into the target object, e.g. a `Store` may mixin an `EventEmitter`. In Java you would use `Store implements EventEmitter` which is a bit more self explaining.